# Installing MySQL on CentOS 5.5

Tags: mysql, centos5

I have to install the latest version of MySQL server community edition 5.1.51 (i think is the latest). I haven't installed any MySQL on this centos machine yet, but when I do a locate mysql - it shows me mysqldump, mysqlshow etc etc on this system.

Now I have downloaded the rpms required :

`MySQL-client-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

MySQL-devel-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

MySQL-embedded-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

MySQL-server-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

MySQL-shared-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

MySQL-test-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm`

When I try to (as root) do the following :
`root@localhost#rpm -ivh MySQL-client-community-5.1.51.rhel5.i386.rpm`

I got a long list of errors saying that the old version conflicts with this one, so I tried to remove mysql (if any) via `rpm -e mysql` it then complained about some dependencies for e.g. `dovecot.x.s.x.` and `lib.something`.

I removed `rpm -e dovecot`
then `rpm -e mysql` and it finished without complaining

I then installed :
`rpm -ivh MySQL-client-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm`
`rpm -ivh MySQL-devel-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm`
`rpm -ivh MySQL-server-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm`
`rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

and when I tried to install :
`rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm` I got the following error :
`Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 from install of MySQL-shared-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.51-1.            rhel5.i386
        file /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 from install of MySQL-shared-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.51-            1.rhel5.i386`

I have checked that MySQL is running and I can login to MySQL Server fine, do you think I need anyother packages for MySQL to function properly, we will be testing a MySQL DB on this machine but on 5.1.51.

Any thoughts / suggestions would be helpful.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to install too much.

In particular, you only need either:

MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm OR MySQL-shared-community-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

Those two are mutually exclusive. The former contains various versions of the mysql libraries for backwards compatibility with software that's linked to those specific library versions.
Pick MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.51-1.rhel5.i386.rpm if you're in doubt.

In short. The 4 RPMs you installed is enough for a fully functioning MySQL server. All is good.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was `yum groupinstall mysql` and [Google search results](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/yum-groupinstall-mysql-database/) suggest this is possible - is the latest version not available at the repositories?

---

EDIT

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121502/installing-a-specific-package-version-with-yum

Comment: thanks for the prompt response - no i did a yum install on another box and it was 5.0.x.x something - so not the latest or it was 5.1.41 (not sure now - would have to check) - there shouldn't be no harm in installing via rpm -ivh ?

Comment: So far as I know, the only problems with installing from RPMs are the ones you experienced - that you have to sort out the dependency issues yourself. Also that maybe yum no longer knows what software you have on your machine - which may have consequences for later use of yum.

Comment: I have installed it already on this centos vm and just did a yum update, haven't faced any issue yet - so hope it stays like that :-) 
This would just be a basic CentOS MySQL DB VM and nothing else - so I guess it should be safe (not in production - just testing).